# Storing categories and subcategories with the possibility of infinite sub-'s, and a function to return them all from MYSQL into JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

My current function:

```
$categories = array();
$db -> new PDO(connect);

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM categories') as $row) {

     $category = array();
     array_push($category, $row['categoryID']);
     foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE categoryID = {$row['categoryID']} ") as $row2) 
     {
          if ($row2["subcatparentID"] == null) {
               $category[$row['categoryID']][] = $row2['subcatID'];
          }
          //Here I need to get all the subcats with parent subcats, and 
          //then I need to add the subcategory to $category finding the parent subcategory
          //mentioned before. So, I need a infinite multi-dimensional search function or something..
          //Plus, I need to use a repeating while loop to make sure all subcategories with 
          //parents are added into the array, because if 14 is linked to 11 and 11 is linked to
     }
 $categories[] = $category;
}

return json_encode($categories);
```

That's my only idea, currently. How do I find the parent subcategory if it can be in any dimension? For example, subcategory 11 is linked to 12, 12 is linked to 14, 14 is linked to 13, I will have $category[13][14][12][11]

My table structure is like this:

table "subcategories": subcatID, categoryID, name, subcatparentID

table "categories": categoryID, name //these are main categories

in return with JSON format I would like something like this:

```
{"1":[41[43,42[45, 44]]],"2":[26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40],"3":[56,57,58,59,60,61],"4":[62,63,64],"5":[1,2,3,4,5,6,21[22,23]]}
```

although that doesn't seem to work with JSON.parse, strangely enough.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries. That means your main choices are either to set up a recursive mysql proc to return the details, have a recursive function in you chosen scripting langauge to repeatedly execute SQL, or redesign your database to use a nested set method. Which is best will depend on the situation (ie, nested set method is very fast to reading, but slow for updates)

Comment: It's impossible to search through a multidimensional array?

Comment: In a single query using the adjacency set model that you are using it isn't possible. You need to do recursive queries (which can take a long time).

Answer (score 1):

Idea for a recursive way of doing this:-

```
<?php

$categories = array();
$db -> new PDO(connect);

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM categories') as $row) 
{
    $categories[$row['categoryID']] = get_sub_categories($db, $row['categoryID']);
}

return json_encode($categories);

function get_sub_categories($db, $parent_category)
{
    $return_categories = array();
    foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE categoryID = $parent_category ") as $row2) 
    {
        $return_categories[$row2['subcatID']] = get_sub_categories($db, $row2['subcatID']);
    }
    return $return_categories;
}

?>
```

Not tested, but this is to give you an array where the key is the category and the value is an array of catgories under that category (which in turn could each be arrays, etc)

EDIT - Still not 100%, but doing this with a loop around but starting at the bottom of the tree, using array_unshift to prepend the sub categories to the array for each category.

This is relying on subcatparentID being set to 0 when a sub category is the highest one under that category, but if something else that is easy to change.

Not tested

```
<?php

$categories = array();
$db -> new PDO(connect);

$categories = array();

foreach($db->query('SELECT categories.categoryID, a.subcatID, a.subcatparentID
                    FROM categories
                    INNER JOIN subcategories a ON categories.categoryID = a.categoryID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategories b ON a.categoryID = b.categoryID AND a.subcatID = b.subcatparentID
                    WHERE b.subcatID IS NULL
                    ') as $row) 
{
    $categories[$row['categoryID']] = array();
    $parent = $row['subcatparentID']
    while($parent != 0)
    {
        // following should only get a single row
        foreach($db->query("SELECT subcatID, subcatparentID FROM subcategories WHERE categoryID = $row['categoryID'] AND subcatID = $parent") as $row2) 
        {
            array_unshift($categories[$row['categoryID']], $row2['subcatID']);
            $parent = $row2['subcatparentID']
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand this, sadly. You're not using parentID?

Comment: It is a basic example of a recursive function getting child records, and their child records, etc, of a category. But I am not certain of the way your tables are structured though. If you can modify your original post with the table structures and a bit of sample data and what you would like output from that sample data I can try and come up with something that better matches your requirements.

Comment: I would like an array for javascript to use like Categories[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] where Categories[2][29,30,31,34,35] are linked, and then for Categories[2][35][32][33] for example.

I edited the original post with table formats.

Comment: So what do you do when a parent has 2 direct children? Is it a full array for each possible chain of parents / children?

Comment: Give that a try. Might not be quite the right format but should be close.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't really work. It does work with the recursive stuff, but it forgets all the other subcategories that should be assigned to the main categories.

Comment: Can you add some sample date to the original post and exactly what you want produced from that sample data please?

Comment: I added some more data

Comment: So you do not want a full array for each chain, rather arrays of arrays of arrays? I will have a play.

Comment: What does the first query do, how do it work? WHERE b.subcatID IS NULL??

Comment: It is finding a sub category (on alias a) that does not have any sub categories itself (ie, does a LEFT JOIN of b onto a, and checks for the value of a field on b being NULL to check no record has been found on b).